# How to write a "find and replace all BUT" function in R?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe that looks roughly like below (meaning that it is an approximation made for illustration, and not an exact replica of the dataframe you can download through the link below, or get from the dput() I pasted below):

```
March_created_at    March_email March_type  April_created_at April_email    April_type
3/11/12 7:28    jeremy@asynk.ch PushEvent   4/1/12 4:03                     PushEvent
3/11/12 7:28    jeremy@asynk.ch PushEvent   4/1/12 4:03                     PushEvent
3/11/12 7:28    jeremy@asynk.ch PushEvent   4/1/12 4:03                     PushEvent
3/11/12 7:28    jeremy@asynk.ch PushEvent   4/1/12 7:03     high            IssuesEvent
3/11/12 11:06   medium          PushEvent   4/1/12 13:57    medium          PushEvent
3/11/12 11:06   medium          PushEvent   4/1/12 13:57    medium          PushEvent
3/11/12 11:06   medium          PushEvent   4/1/12 13:57    medium          PushEvent
3/11/12 12:46                   PushEvent   
3/11/12 12:46                   PushEvent   
3/11/12 12:46                   PushEvent
```

The full dataset can be found [here](https://github.com/aronlindberg/VOSS-Sequencing-Toolkit/blob/master/rubinius_rubinius_sequencing/output.csv) as a CSV file

I'm looking to write a function that takes the following inputs:

1. A dataframe
2. Certain columns of that dataframe
3. A list of strings (e.g. a set of email addresses)
4. A replacement string (e.g. "low")

Now, I want the function to go through only the specified columns of that dataframe and replace all of the strings (as well as empty cells) that *do not* match the list of strings specified in point 3 above with the replacement string in point 4. However, this should only be done if the following condition holds:

*The cell under consideration needs to have a timestamp for the same month.*

For example, let's say we are about to replace the empty cell on row 8 in column "March_email". I can see that on row 8 in the column "March_created_at" there is a timestamp, so I can go ahead and replace this empty cell with the specified string (e.g. "low"). However, look at row 8 in the column "April_email". This cell is also empty, and so is the cell on row 8 in column "April_created_at". In this case, nothing should be done (i.e. no string inserted).

The reason I want to do this is that certain cells are just empty because there is no data, so nothing should be inserted. Other cells are empty because the data is missing, so I need to impute the data based on the function I specified above.

How can I accomplish this in R?

**Appendix:** Here is a dput() of the head of the dataset:

```
structure(list(March_created_at = c("2012-03-11 07:28:04", "2012-03-11 07:28:04", 
"2012-03-11 07:28:04", "2012-03-11 07:28:19", "2012-03-11 07:28:19", 
"2012-03-11 07:28:19"), March_actor_attributes_email = c("jeremy@asynk.ch", 
"jeremy@asynk.ch", "jeremy@asynk.ch", "jeremy@asynk.ch", "jeremy@asynk.ch", 
"jeremy@asynk.ch"), March_type = c("PushEvent", "PushEvent", 
"PushEvent", "PushEvent", "PushEvent", "PushEvent"), April_created_at = c("2012-04-01     04:03:13", 
"2012-04-01 04:03:13", "2012-04-01 04:03:13", "2012-04-01 07:03:11", 
"2012-04-01 07:03:11", "2012-04-01 07:03:11"), April_actor_attributes_email = c("", 
"", "", "high", "high", "high"), April_type = c("PushEvent", 
"PushEvent", "PushEvent", "IssuesEvent", "IssuesEvent", "IssuesEvent"
), May_created_at = c("2012-05-01 00:16:05", "2012-05-01 00:16:05", 
"2012-05-01 00:16:05", "2012-05-01 01:03:19", "2012-05-01 01:03:19", 
"2012-05-01 01:03:19"), May_actor_attributes_email = c("john.firebaugh@gmail.com", 
"john.firebaugh@gmail.com", "john.firebaugh@gmail.com", "mitch.tishmack@gmail.com", 
"mitch.tishmack@gmail.com", "mitch.tishmack@gmail.com"), May_type = c("PushEvent", 
"PushEvent", "PushEvent", "IssueCommentEvent", "IssueCommentEvent", 
"IssueCommentEvent"), June_created_at = c("2012-06-01 00:25:05", 
"2012-06-01 00:25:05", "2012-06-01 00:25:05", "2012-06-01 00:42:29", 
"2012-06-01 00:42:29", "2012-06-01 00:42:29"), June_actor_attributes_email =     c("michaelklishin@me.com", 
"michaelklishin@me.com", "michaelklishin@me.com", "", "", ""), 
    June_type = c("IssueCommentEvent", "IssueCommentEvent", "IssueCommentEvent", 
    "PushEvent", "PushEvent", "PushEvent"), July_created_at = c("2012-07-01 13:46:20", 
    "2012-07-01 13:46:20", "2012-07-02 11:53:37", "2012-07-02 11:53:37", 
    "2012-07-02 12:27:30", "2012-07-02 12:27:30"), July_actor_attributes_email = c("medium", 
    "medium", "ryoqun@gmail.com", "ryoqun@gmail.com", "ryoqun@gmail.com", 
    "ryoqun@gmail.com"), July_type = c("PushEvent", "PushEvent", 
    "CreateEvent", "CreateEvent", "PushEvent", "PushEvent"), 
    August_created_at = c("2012-08-01 00:04:09", "2012-08-01 00:04:09", 
    "2012-08-01 00:04:42", "2012-08-01 00:04:42", "2012-08-01 00:05:04", 
    "2012-08-01 00:05:04"), August_actor_attributes_email = c("jeremy@asynk.ch", 
    "jeremy@asynk.ch", "jeremy@asynk.ch", "jeremy@asynk.ch", 
    "jeremy@asynk.ch", "jeremy@asynk.ch"), August_type = c("IssueCommentEvent", 
    "IssueCommentEvent", "IssuesEvent", "IssuesEvent", "IssueCommentEvent", 
    "IssueCommentEvent"), September_created_at = c("2012-09-01 18:12:24", 
    "2012-09-01 18:12:24", "2012-09-01 23:51:18", "2012-09-01 23:51:18", 
    "2012-09-02 00:34:54", "2012-09-02 00:34:54"), September_actor_attributes_email = c("ryoqun@gmail.com", 
    "ryoqun@gmail.com", "ryoqun@gmail.com", "ryoqun@gmail.com", 
    "ryoqun@gmail.com", "ryoqun@gmail.com"), September_type = c("CommitCommentEvent", 
    "CommitCommentEvent", "CreateEvent", "CreateEvent", "PushEvent", 
    "PushEvent"), October_created_at = c("2012-10-01 07:48:38", 
    "2012-10-01 10:01:40", "2012-10-01 10:01:43", "2012-10-01 10:17:00", 
    "2012-10-01 16:08:29", "2012-10-01 18:06:46"), October_actor_attributes_email = c("medium", 
    "medium", "medium", "medium", "", "core"), October_type = c("PushEvent", 
    "IssuesEvent", "PushEvent", "PushEvent", "ForkEvent", "PullRequestEvent"
    )), .Names = c("March_created_at", "March_actor_attributes_email", 
"March_type", "April_created_at", "April_actor_attributes_email", 
"April_type", "May_created_at", "May_actor_attributes_email", 
"May_type", "June_created_at", "June_actor_attributes_email", 
"June_type", "July_created_at", "July_actor_attributes_email", 
"July_type", "August_created_at", "August_actor_attributes_email", 
"August_type", "September_created_at", "September_actor_attributes_email", 
"September_type", "October_created_at", "October_actor_attributes_email", 
"October_type"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This question was downvoted. Can the person explain why, so that I can improve the quality of the question?

Comment: It was not me, but I assume it is because it is very localized. Its not asking about a problem with R but instead with a specific implementation goal.  If you hover over the down arrow I would assume it falls into the last category.  Its unlikely to be useful to others.

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this:

```
myfun <- function(month, DF, matches, replacement) {
  email.col <- paste0(month, '_actor_attributes_email')
  date.col  <- paste0(month, '_created_at')


  DF[[email.col]] <- ifelse(DF[[date.col]] != '' & !DF[[email.col]] %in% matches,
                            DF[[email.col]],
                            replacement)

  return (DF[, c(date.col, email.col)])
}

myfun(dat, 'April', 'high', 'foo')

#          April_created_at April_actor_attributes_email
# 1 2012-04-01     04:03:13                          foo   
# 2     2012-04-01 04:03:13                          foo   
# 3     2012-04-01 04:03:13                          foo   
# 4     2012-04-01 07:03:11                          high
# 5     2012-04-01 07:03:11                          high
# 6     2012-04-01 07:03:11                          high
```

Then, you can just feed it a bunch of months...

```
out <- lapply(list('March', 'April', 'May'), 
              myfun, DF=dat, matches='', replacement='foo')
```

And you can get that back into a data.frame right quick. with `plyr`

```
as.data.frame(unlist(out, recursive=FALSE))
```

There are plenty of other ways and options but this should give you a big start.